# avx512 strided gather with arbitrary stride

Tags: avx512

I know in AVX512 you can perform strided gathers with strides of 1,2,4,8. However what if I have an arbitrary stride that can be anywhere between 10-1000? The stride is known at compile time. I understand then the instruction won't be the bottleneck, the memory probably will be. Is _mm512_set_ps the most effective way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *strided gathers with strides of 1,2,4,8*

No, there's no special support for that; maybe you're thinking of ARM/ARM64 NEON `vld4` 4-way deinterleave?

In x86 you can use 1,2,4, or 8 as a *scale factors* for an index vector for `vpgatherdd` / `vpgatherdps`, but if you just want every 2nd element it's better to manually shuffle (e.g. `_mm512_permutex2var_ps` to grab alternate floats from 2 input vectors), getting many useful elements with one wide load instead of accessing cache once per element.

---

But in your case, with a minimum stride of 10, at most 2 elements will come from the same 16 x 32-bit 512-bit vector, and with wider strides not even one per vector.

So you can use `vpgatherdps` with `_mm512_add_epi32(idx, _mm512_set1_epi32(16 * stride))` in a loop.  **Or better, just use a fixed vector of indices and increment the base pointer.**  You might generate that vector of indices with `_mm512_mullo_epi32(_mm512_setr_epi32(0,1,2,3,...,15), _mm512_set1_epi32(stride))`.  Since a float is 4 bytes wide, use a scale factor of `4` with your gathers.

Even if you need to handle huge arrays, incrementing the pointer instead of the vector elements avoids any need for 64-bit indices, as well as minimizing the number of vector uops.  (Valuable when using 512-bit vectors on current CPUs.)

---

IIRC, Intel's optimization manual has a section about strided loads and the tradeoff in manual gather vs. using gather instructions.  Gather instructions become relatively better the wider your vectors are (2/clock load throughput but only 1/clock shuffle throughput for most shuffles), so especially for 512-bit vectors its likely a win to use vector shuffles.

Comment: How efficient is using _mm512_i32gather_ps with the indices as you described compared to writing something like _mm512_set_ps(input[a15],input[a14]...) ?

Comment: @bumpbump: That's exactly what I was talking about; if you look at the compiler asm output for that `_mm512_set_ps`, it will involve about 15 shuffle instructions; some may manage to use memory source operands like `vmovhps`, but it still has to combine 128-bit chunks into 256-bit, then vinsertf32x8 to combine those.  If you're not sure, benchmark it as part of your real use-case.

Comment: Will the individual loads in `vpgatherdps` be able to take advantage of the ip prefetcher? If not maybe scalar + `vpsinrd` will be faster for larger strides?

Comment: @Noah: The L2 prefetcher should detect the stride pattern; maybe not the L1d prefetcher, I don't know.  OoO exec can probably hide that L2-hit latency if the gather latency isn't part of the critical path of a loop-carried dep chain.  Or if you're memory bottlenecked (quite likely even if hot in L3, depending on how much work you do with each vector), then you just want to minimize uops so OoO exec can see nice and far ahead (across page boundaries where prefetch doesn't work as well).

Comment: @PeterCordes do you know resources on how OoO exec interacts with microcode/how much OoO exec there is in microcode? If its memory bottlenecked can't imagine `vpgatherd` being faster because IP prefetcher unless there is some advantage to OoO exec from microcode. AFAIK unless your bottleneck is FE (unlikely with a tight loop like this) any backend bottleneck on OoO exec will be just a present for the microcode uops from `vpgatherd` as normal loads. Also would be concerned about DSB/MITE transitions (ingeneral microcode in a loop scares me).